# Tried updating code mirror text area with css but it doesn't change anything

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, codemirror

Right Now I am trying to create a code editor in the browser.

For the syntax highlighting I chose to use code mirror. the problem with code mirror is that when we use a code mirror "object" it can't use regular js properly and my whole code was structured around listeners and stuff.

So I found a work around. I wanted to create 2 text area that one will be on top of the other. the top one will be the "code mirror" text area and the other which is not seen will be a normal text area.

I wanted to do it so when I click on the code mirror text area I would basically focus on the normal text area behind and basically update the code mirror text area when typing on the one below.

After coding this I currently have 2 text areas one below the other (see the picture)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipMUl.png) current state

but when I try to put them one over the other it just doesn't work

I tried using bootstrap to do it instead of normal css because this is what I used in the project and I thought this is what interfered. still nothing has changed

I tried using inline css because I thought that maybe something is overriding the css from the code mirror. still nothing has changed

I tried adding !important rule to the css to maybe change something. nothing has changed..

code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.62.2/codemirror.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.62.2/theme/dracula.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.62.2/codemirror.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.62.2/mode/python/python.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
  .form-group-relative {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .code-textarea {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  
  .form-control {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
  }
</style>

{% endblock head %}

{% block content %}
<h1 class="text-center mb-5">Webide Python Interpreter</h1>
  

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <form id="form">
            <div class="form-group mb-3 form-group-relative">
              <textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="20" id="text-area" class="form-control"></textarea>
              <textarea name="code" id="code" rows="20" cols="50" class="code-textarea"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group mb-3" role="group">
              <button type="submit" id="run-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mr-2">Run</button>
              <button type="button" id="stop-btn" class="btn btn-danger mr-2">Stop</button>
              <button type="button" id="clear-terminal-btn" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">Clear Terminal</button>
              <button type="button" id="share-link-btn" class="btn btn-info">Share Invite Link</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  const codeTextArea = document.getElementById("code");
  const textArea = document.getElementById("text-area");

  codeTextArea.addEventListener("focus", () => {
    textArea.focus();
  });
</script>
```